# How can I simulate datas from Heart Rate sensor on Android Wear Emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, wear-os

As the title, how can I do to "simulate" some values from the emulated heart rate sensor from the emulator? Is this possible on the official emulator or do you know some alternative emulators that do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't, android emulator can't simulate any sensors. Android Wear emulators can't do it too

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Is there any other emulator that can do this?

Comment: If you want to simulate Android Wear, there is no other emulators

Answer (score 4):

Updating this answer for 2021. With the current emulator, you can click "..." in the emulator's menu and navigate to "Virtual Sensors -> Additional Sensors". Here you can move the heart rate slider to control it.

Comment: I just tried, ist it working? I didn't get onSensorChange() called from the virtual heart rate sensor. My android emulator version 30.6.5, My Wear OS Image API 28, rev 5. All from stable channel. Is this function active in beta channel?

Comment: You need to move the slider to get updates. The emulator quite literally needs the sensor reading to be ‘changed’ for new values to be sent

Comment: Thanks, I am aware that the slider need to be moved and I also moved it to trigger onChange sensor event. But still no onSensorChanged event fired. Is your emulator also run on Macosx? Is the wear os image x86 or Arm?

Comment: @YingdingWang I was running the emulator on ubuntu 20.04. Have you been able to test your app on a normal device, or are you just testing on the emulator?

Comment: I just double checked again. My app code works on real device: https://github.com/yingding/android-examples/tree/master/WearSensorExamples , but not get any onSensorChanged event from the virtual sensor of emulator on Macosx. I will fire a bug report.

Comment: I would try deleting the emulator and recreating it using android device manager. Are you using api 28?

Comment: Yes, I used Wear OS Image API 28, Rev5. I have already removed the wear os vm and recreated it, wipe out the data and cold restarted. In the mean time I have fired a bug report https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/188096928

Comment: I think a big report is the way to go here. Mine is working as expected so there must be an issue with the chipset or mac os.

Answer (score 2):

**LOCATE HEART RATE VIRTUAL SENSOR**

If you can not find the heart rate sensor under "Additional Sensors" as described in [Scott's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67492404/11039164), you need to add this line below to your AVD's `config.ini` file.

```
hw.sensors.heart_rate=yes
```

For MacOS, the `config.ini` file can be found at this path:

```
/Users/{your user name}/.android/avd/{your AVD name}.avd/config.ini
```

**INCLUDE PERMISSION:**

You also need to request the `android.permission.BODY_SENSORS`.

> This sensor requires permission android.permission.BODY_SENSORS. It
> will not be returned by SensorManager.getSensorsList nor
> SensorManager.getDefaultSensor if the application doesn't have this
> permission.
>
> Source: [Android Heart Rate Sensor documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#:%7E:text=This%20sensor%20requires%20permission%20android.permission.BODY_SENSORS.%20It%20will%20not%20be%20returned%20by%20SensorManager.getSensorsList%20nor%20SensorManager.getDefaultSensor%20if%20the%20application%20doesn%27t%20have%20this%20permission).

You can do that using the following methods:

> ```java
> public void permissionRequest(){
>     if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.BODY_SENSORS)
>             != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
>         requestPermissions(
>                 new String[]{Manifest.permission.BODY_SENSORS},
>                 MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_BODY_SENSOR);
>     }
>     else{
>         Log.d(TAG,"ALREADY GRANTED");
>     } 
> }
> ```
>
> OR you can enable it from Settings>Apps>YOUR_APP>Permissions>Sensor
>
> Source: https://gist.github.com/mjohnsullivan/557c2f19ba177312b1d7?permalink_comment_id=2615046#gistcomment-2615046