# Proper different amplitude values for vibration

Tags: java, android

I am working on this app where I need to provide three different vibration intensities. The three intensities are associated with a heart symbol. I want strong, medium, and low heart beat/vibration. The amplitude possible values (according to documentation) are 0-255 where 0 is no vibration and 255 is the strongest vibration possible. Now, I can assign 255 for the strong beat. Though, I do not know what values to assign to medium and low heart beats. My devices do not support amplitudes because they are old. So, I am stuck.

I wonder if anyone could give me some proper values or direct me to an article. I tried searching without any luck.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT
(Added a vibration considered as output answer)

---

### Considering the heart beat (vibration) as input.

According to the Android Dev Docs the sensor event [`TYPE_HEART_RATE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor#TYPE_HEART_RATE) gives you the heart rate in beats per minute.

The decision about what heart beat rate ranges are low, medium or strong relies on medical info and what your app is for.

If for example you are willing to label the heart beat rate while a person is not doing any exercise (Resting Heart Rate) then you can check for example [here](https://www.heart.org/en/healthy-living/fitness/fitness-basics/target-heart-rates) that the normal rate stays between 60 and 100 and you could also consider many other variables like age, sex, etc.

About coding without a device that actually could give you a sensor measure you could try to create an Android Wear Emulator with the last SDK but I'm afraid they used to not be able to simulate heart beats as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31720257/how-can-i-simulate-datas-from-heart-rate-sensor-on-android-wear-emulator).

Anyways, just create a copied method for testing (or better overload the one that reacts to the sensor event) and call that method with some heart beat rates you have predefined in your code. Call that method with different values and check if the symbol for the heart updates accordingly.

Then just hope you are properly capturing the event from the sensor and check it on a real device when you can.

---

### Considering the vibration as output

In this case I'm afraid you won't be able to test the intensity without a real device and also have in mind the intensity highly depends on the device itself (vibrating motor strength). There are complex ways to try to control the vibration intensity given the kernel type (like you could find [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28851/increase-vibrate-strength)) but it looks like you don't need any of that.

Since the vibration intensity by itself apparently can't be controlled read the ideas on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888043/controlling-vibration-intensity-in-android-phones-is-it-possible) . They suggest you to use non vibration intervals in the vibration patterns to make the vibration feel "weaker".

In his code he uses gaps of 15 milliseconds of vibration + 15 milliseconds of non vibration so use that as a reference for now until you have real feedback and go with something like:

- Continuous vibration for Strong.
- Vibrations of 15 ms + 15 ms no vibration intervals for Medium.
- Vibrations of 15 ms + 30 ms no vibration intervals for Low.

Then, when you have the feedback just adjust the non vibration gaps and that will be it.

For newer devices that accept amplitude start with patterns based on amplitudes like:

- 255*(1/3) for low.
- 255*(2/3) for medium.
- 255 for strong.

And again, readjust when you have feedback.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply to my question. I am not sure if you understood my question or not. I want three different settings for representing a heart beat. Like for example, an idea that is liked so much would make the heart symbol bigger and the user receives a strong vibration effect. If the idea is normal he would get a medium vibration. If the idea is not liked the user would get a low vibration. I know the strongest would be 255. Without a device to test various amplitude values, I cannot determine what I should assign the medium and low vibrations. This is not a medical app.

Comment: True @knowledgeseeker, I thought you were talking about the input beat (vibration) since you were mentioning a heart symbol but you were talking about output vibration.

Comment: I've edited the answer to consider the vibration as output @knowledgeseeker

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply to my question. I appreciate it. Though, I am actually referring to the amplitude values for Android Oreo devices (and up). I am not considering old devices. On Android O and up you get two arguments for creating a vibration pattern. Timings and amplitude. The amplitude controls how strong the vibration is. My problem is that I lack an Android O device to test the amplitude values  to see what values would be suitable for moderate and low. I hope I made it clear now.

Comment: Here is a link to a sample function on the documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/VibrationEffect#createWaveform(long[],%20int[],%20int)

Comment: When I was editing I was going to suggest to start with amplitudes of 255*(1/3) for low, 255*(2/3) for medium and 255 for strong too for newer devices. I'll add that too.

Comment: I appreciate the effort, SaintJob 2.0. I can deduce values but I would rather not do it. I am looking for someone with an experience on the subject and/or a device on which he can test the values on. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you can generate a vibration pattern (assuming that your devices only support (0) no vibration and (255) maximum vibration only).

To start with, you should have Vibration permission declared in your AndroidManifest.xml:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>`

Then you can use this code:

```
import android.os.Vibrator;
Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
long[] vibrationPattern = {0, 100, 500, 300};
// must support new VibrationEffect API 26
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    v.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createWaveform(vibrationPattern, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));
} else {
    //deprecated in API 26 
    v.vibrate(vibrationPattern, -1);
}
```

Lets take a look at the vibration pattern generated as an example.
It starts with 0 which means 0 delay in milliseconds, then vibrate at full for 100ms, delay 500ms then vibrate again 300ms. You can obviously create different patterns as long and custom as you want. Please chech if `v.hasVibrator()` before calling those methods otherwise your app can crash if some device do not support it.

I hope i've helped!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply to my question. I am not actually asking for older devices. I want to provide this feature for new Oreo devices (but I do not have any to experiment with values). I just want the values. 255 for strong (that I know), ? for medium, and ? for low. Those are the values I want. Regards.

Comment: Please note that it is impossible to change the "intensity" of vibration. It only supports On/Off state. You can artificially simulate different vibration intensities by creating different patterns with custom on/off timing in ms, as i suggested on the answer below. Take a look at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html

Comment: Hello again. Please refer to this method and the amplitude part: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/VibrationEffect#createWaveform(long[],%20int[],%20int)

Comment: You can do it with long durationMs = 1000; int amplitude = any value between 0-255; VibrationEffect.createOneShot(durationMs, amplitude); but keep in mind it will only work on API level 26 or higher.